# Title insertion problem

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, document-classes

I am using the following code to create a table. I'd like to add title to it, but when I use the `\caption` command it sends the following error message:

> \caption outside float. \caption

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = *, itemsep=-3pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep}, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\partopsep}}

\begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}
\hline
foo
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\item is raggedright and allows manual line breaks 
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\end{itemize} 
&
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows \newline
manual line breaks \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}

\caption{Table1 to test captions and labels}

\end{document}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me sort this problem out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `table`environment around `tabular`.

Comment: Or use `\captionof{table}{Table to test captions}` etc. (Requires `caption` package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a table with a caption *exactly at this point* in your text, use the package `caption` or `capt-of` and the command `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of `\caption`.

[image]

(Note that your `tabular` is too wide for the current `\textwidth`, hence the table is out of center.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{caption}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = *, itemsep=-3pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep}, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\partopsep}}

\begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}
\hline
foo
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\item is raggedright and allows manual line breaks 
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\end{itemize} 
&
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows \newline
manual line breaks \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{Table1 to test captions and labels}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to allow your table to float more or less freely in order to facilitate better page breaks, just wrap your `tabular` and `\caption` into a `table` environment. (No extra package needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = *, itemsep=-3pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep}, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\partopsep}}

\begin{table}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}
\hline
foo
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\item is raggedright and allows manual line breaks 
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\end{itemize} 
&
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows \newline
manual line breaks \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table1 to test captions and labels}
\end{table}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```